# Change the color of a bar chart with having threshold value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

In Jqplot I have only one series of data, but having threshold value of 200. I need to change the color as shown below. How is this possible?
[image: series of data having threshold value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it is to define an array of colors defined according to your data values.

For that purpose, you can do a preprocessing before plotting your graph. You need to iterate over your data and add either red or blue in your colors array according to the threshold value :

```
var data = [['Nissan', 4],['Porche', 6],['Acura', 2],['Aston Martin', 5],['Rolls Royce', 6]];
var colors = [];
var threshold = 5;
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    if(value[1] > threshold)
      colors.push("#FF0000");
    else
      colors.push("#0000FF");
});
```

Please see a working example [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/aM2b4/)

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var data = [['Nissan', 460],['Porche', -260],['Acura', 690],['Aston Martin', 820],['Rolls Royce', 850]];
var colors = [];
var threshold = -200;
$.each(data, function(index, value){
    if(value[1] < threshold)
      colors.push("#FF0000");
    else
      colors.push("#0000FF");
});
plot = $.jqplot('chart1', [data], {
    title:'Bar Chart with Varying Colors',
    seriesColors: colors,
    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            fillToZero: true,
            varyBarColor: true,
            animation: {speed: 2500},
            useNegativeColors: false
        }
    },
    axes:{
        xaxis:{
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
        }
    }
});
```

});